# how to use existing field of a class in @Any column in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Assume that there are 3 classes A, B and C such that A is the super class for B and C.  Consider class X which can refer any of B and C. I know that using @Any will solve my problem.But I have a problem that there's an already existing field 'type' in X which identifies uniquely which of B or C to use. I want to know how can I use @Any annotation without creating another new column( using the field 'type' only) to identify the table where relationship is to be mapped.

```
public Class X{
 private int type;
 private A a;
}
```

Another thing is if I remove the type field in X, is there a way to get the value of metaColumn of @Any except using a direct sql query ?

Comment: " I have a problem that there's an already existing field 'type' in X which identifies uniquely which of B or C to use "  how  you compare  primitive int with wrapper ?

Comment: say type==0 means 'a' in X will load class B's object, type==1 means class C's object

Comment: in that case you can use instanceof  operator of java  to compare object is of type A or B like if (type instanceOf classA) then map corresponding table